# Is it feasible to have the training set < the test set after undersampling the majority class?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science, imbalanced-data

I have a data set of 1500 records with two classes which are imbalanced. Class 0 is 1300 records while Class 1 is 200 records, hence a ratio of ard 6.5:1.

I built a random forest with this data set for classification. I know from past experience, if I use the whole data set, the recall is pretty low, which is probably due to the imbalanced class.

So I decided to undersample Class 0. My steps are as follows:

1. Randomly split the data set into train & test set of ratio 7:3 (hence 1050 for training and 450 for test.)
2. Now the train set has ~900 data of Class 0 ~100 for Class 1. I clustered ~900 data of Class 0, and undersample it (proportionally) to ~100 records.

So now train set ~100 Class 0 + ~100 Class 1 = ~200 records in total while the test set is 70 Class 0 + 380 Class 1 = 450 records in total.

Here comes my questions:

1) Are my steps valid? I split the train/test first and then undersample the majority class of the train set.

2) Now my train set (~200) < test set (450). Does it make sense?

3) The performance is still not very good. Precision is 0.34, recall is 0.72 and the f1 score is 0.46. Is there any way to improve? Should I use CV?

Many thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Are my steps valid? I split the train/test first and then
>   undersample the majority class of the train set.

You should split `train` and `test` so the **class balance is preserved in both**. If in your **whole dataset** ratio is `6.5:1` it should be the same both in `train` and `test`.

Yes, you should split it before undersampling (no need to undersample `test` cases), just remember to monitor multiple metrics (e.g. `f1 score`, `recall`, `precision` were already mentioned and you should be fine with those) as you are training on different distribution than `test`.

> 2) Now my train set (~200) < test set (450). Does it make sense?

Yes it does. You may also go for `oversampling` on training dataset (e.g. `minority` class is repeated at random to match the number of examples from `majority`). In this case **you have to split before as well** otherwise you may spoil your `test` set with `training` samples which is even more disastrous.

> 3) The performance is still not very good. Precision is 0.34, recall is 0.72 and the f1 score is 0.46. Is there any way to improve? Should I use CV?

It depends on specific problem, what I would do:

- `oversampling` instead of `undersampling` - neural networks need a lot of data, you don't have many samples right now
- try other non-DL algorithms (maybe `SVM` if you have a lot of features? `RandomForest` otherwise might be a good bet as well)
- otherwise fine tune your neural network (focus especially on `learning rate`, use CV or related methods if you got the time)
- try to use some pretrained neural networks if available for the task at hand